# Error compiling androidplot

Tags: android, plot, androidplot

I'm trying to use the android plot library, just copy the code of the sample page

http://androidplot.com/docs/quickstart/

I add the librery source and  just  change the following line in the example code because it was giving me an error:

```
// Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using LineAndPointRenderer
    // and configure it from xml:
    LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter();
    series1Format.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());
    series1Format.configure(getApplicationContext(),
            R.xml.line_point_formatter_with_plf1);
```

I change the last line for:

```
R.layout.line_point_formatter_with_plf1);
```

The program takes several minutes to compile and give a lot of errors like the following

Android Dex: [prueba graficos] (org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler$1) that doesn't come with an

Android Dex: [prueba graficos] associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a

Android Dex: [prueba graficos] and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring

I also hava an error whit the style, in the example the style is style="@style/sample_activity"  but I dont have that style so I just set the layout size.

And in the layout/xml/line_point_formatter_with_plf1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config
    linePaint.strokeWidth="3dp"
    linePaint.color="#00AA00"
    vertexPaint.color="#007700"
    fillPaint.color="#00000000"
    pointLabelFormatter.textPaint.color="#FFFFFF"/>
```

The word config algo give me an error: layout_height' attribute should be defined.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a slight error in the tutorial you provided : 
the files line_point_formatter_plf1.xml and line_point_formatter_plf2.xml should be under the folder res/xml/ if there is no xml folder under the res/ folder just create it and it will accept the config tag without problems.

It's because you're putting them under layout/ that it consider's them as layout files and tells you 'config' tag as a root is not acceptable for a layout xml file.

And for the "layout_height' attribute should be defined" error, just add those 2 lines :

```
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

to the root tag of the simple_xy_plot_example.xml file (this error has nothing to do with the config tag)

Your simple_xy_plot_example.xml file should look like this  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              style="@style/AppTheme"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
            android:id="@+id/mySimpleXYPlot"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            androidPlot.title="A Simple XY Plot"
            androidPlot.domainLabel="Domain"
            androidPlot.rangeLabel="Range"
            androidPlot.titleWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
            androidPlot.domainLabelWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.rangeLabelWidget.labelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginTop="20dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginLeft="15dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginBottom="25dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.marginRight="10dp"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_tick_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.rangeOriginLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/range_tick_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.domainLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_tick_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.domainOriginLabelPaint.textSize="@dimen/domain_tick_label_font_size"
            androidPlot.legendWidget.textPaint.textSize="@dimen/legend_text_font_size"
            androidPlot.legendWidget.iconSizeMetrics.heightMetric.value="15dp"
            androidPlot.legendWidget.iconSizeMetrics.widthMetric.value="15dp"
            androidPlot.legendWidget.heightMetric.value="25dp"
            androidPlot.legendWidget.positionMetrics.anchor="right_bottom"
            androidPlot.graphWidget.gridLinePaint.color="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried it and it works fine for me.

Comment: thanks for the help, I try what you say, that solve some of the problems but still fail the compilation, the style part give me an error so I erase that line the rest is the same that you say, here are some of the errors:

Android Dex: [prueba graficos] (org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler$1) that doesn't come with an

Android Dex: [prueba graficos] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

Android Dex: [prueba graficos] Unable to execute DX

Android Dex: [prueba graficos] at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:134)

Comment: for the style put this line instead : 
    style="@style/AppTheme"

(please up vote my answer or  if it did helped you, mark it as correct answer)

Comment: if AppTheme does not work, go to the file styles.xml under res/values/ and check the name attribute of the style tag